# select: accept an unlisted, char input

Tags: bash, select, case, exit

I'm using `bash` `select` to make a multiple choice dialog in which option numbers adjust automatically when I add a new selection between two existing ones.

```
select choice in command1 command2 command3; do
    $choice
    break
done
```

To display something different than the command executed in itself, I've been told to declare an associative array

```
declare -A choices=(
    [Option 1]=command1
    [Option 2]=command2
    [Option 3]=command3
)
select choice in "${!choices[@]}" exit ; do
    [[ $choice == exit ]] && break
    ${choices[$choice]}
done
```

The thing I don't like this way, is that the option to `exit` is viewed as a numbered selection. I'd want to achieve something like

```
PS3="Select the desired option (q to quit): "
```

And make `select` accept `q`, besides `1`, `2` or `3`, as a valid input.

The associative array causes problems with the fact the input is used as index, so I switched to a nested `case`. This way, I also do not have to declare separate functions to store more than one command

```
PS3="Select the desired option (q to quit): "
select choice in "Option 1" "Option 2" "Option 3"; do
    case $choice in
        "Option 1") command1a
                    command1b
                    break;;
        "Option 2") command2a
                    command2b
                    break;;
        "Option 3") command3a
                    command3b
                    break;;
        q)          echo "Bye!"
                    break;;
    esac
done
```

Now there are no problems regarding a non-numerical (or an over-range) input, but `q` as an input is still not recognized. It falls in the the `default` case, executing `*)` if I have defined it, or simply prompting again if I didn't.

Is there any way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use (check the content of) the `$REPLY` variable.

Example:

```
declare -A choices=(
    [Show the date]=show_date
    [Print calendar]=print_cal
    [Say hello]=say_hello
)

show_date() {
    date
}
print_cal() {
    cal
}
say_hello() {
    echo "Hello $USER"
}

PS3="Select the desired option (q to quit): "
select choice in "${!choices[@]}"
do
    case "$choice" in
    '') # handling the invalid entry - e.g. the "q"
        # in a case of an invalid entry, the $choice is en empty(!) string
        # checking the content of the entered line can be done using the $REPLY
        case "$REPLY" in
            q|Q) echo "Bye, bye - quitting...."; exit;;
            *) echo "INVALID choice <$REPLY> - try again";;
        esac
        ;;
    *)
        #valid user input
        ${choices[$choice]}
        ;;
    esac
done
```

or the shorter, but not as flexible

```
declare -A choices=(
    [Show the date]=show_date
    [Print calendar]=print_cal
    [Say hello]=say_hello
)

show_date() {
    date
}
print_cal() {
    cal
}
say_hello() {
    echo "Hello $USER"
}

PS3="Select the desired option (q to quit): "
select choice in "${!choices[@]}"
do
    case "$REPLY" in
    q|Q) echo "Bye, bye - quitting...."; exit;;
    1|2|3) ${choices[$choice]} ;;
    *) echo "INVALID choice <$REPLY> - try again";;
    esac
done
```

Comment: This is awesome! You are awesome! I feel like a learned a lot. There's still one last thing: what do you mean when you say that the method directly handling the `$REPLY` is "not as flexible"? Is it because you manually have to specify all the numbers corresponding to valid inputs, manually?